# Laravel 5.5 : How to define global variable that can be used in all controllers ?

Tags: php, laravel, global-variables, laravel-5.5, controllers

Hello Developers & Coders ,

> My question is How to define a global variable , that can be used in
>   all controllers in Laravel ?

I have defined one variable `$company` in **AppServiceProviders's boot method** - that im using in all blade views , but I can not use it in controllers file , it gives error , `undefined variable $company`

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::share('key', 'value');
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

        $company=DB::table('company')->where('id',1)->first();
        View::share('company',$company);  

    }

     /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

}
```

please guide me , thanks for your efforts & time :)

Comment: if it is static  you can use  .env file or  config file that you create. But if it is dynamic variable you can use session or cache  to use it from everywhere.

Comment: @ErkanÖzkök , as you see in the post , I am using query builder to fetch record from database , the variable is dynamic not static.

Comment: Why should we use AppServiceProvider(answered by @ErkanÖzkök)? Can i use any other service provide??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

set configuration variables at runtime

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
    * Bootstrap any application services.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::share('key', 'value');
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

        $company=DB::table('company')->where('id',1)->first();
        // View::share('company',$company);  
        config(['yourconfig.company' => $company]);
    }
}
```

usage:

```
config('yourconfig.company');
```

Comment: but what if the db doesn't exist yet?

Answer (score -1):

Okay, so unless you want to keep it in your Session, which I absolutely do not recommend, Cache which does not seem to be a best idea either or set it through the Config system inside of a Framework (which already are 3 different solutions suited for different matters) I would start from thinking what that variable will contain, if that's something that's just a Collection of Company model then you can basically use it in any controller by just using Laravel Eloquent methods.

What I recommend is either `$company = Company::where('foo', 'bar')->first();`, or just some data provider that would return all the information that you need in the form of Laravel Collection.

tl;dr

```
#recommended way that's reusable throughout whole app
Company::find(1); // instead of DB::table('company')->where('id', 1)->get();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: `Company::find(1);` and `DB::table('company')->where('id', 1)->get();` . both are same , one is eloquent and one is query builer way , use any way but I want a glabally variable across all controllers

Comment: I'm not sure if using global variable is particularly great practice, and config should be used for configurational variables (thus the name) therefore I still think that unless you want to keep this kind of data inside of Redis, solution I proposed is best one for given problem.